# UIActivity from UIActivityType

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

Is there a way to get UIActivity from and an existing UIActivityType?

So I can construct UIActivityViewController like:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [],
   applicationActivities: [MyActivity(),"TypeUIActivity"])

present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity) about this and I read:

> “**Subclassing Notes**
>
> This class must be subclassed before it can be used. The job of an
>   activity object is to act on the data provided to it and to provide
>   some meta information that iOS can display to the user. For more
>   complex services, an activity object can also display a custom user
>   interface and use it to gather additional information from the user. “

That means you’ll need to create a custom implementation of UIActivity and override its functionality to create the method you wish to use. Like creating a custom implementation of a CollectionViewCell.